# GCC behaviour when calling a function with too many arguments

Tags: c, gcc

I just noticed a behaviour with GCC that seems strange to me (not checked with other compilers).

If I compile this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int i)
{
  printf("Hello %d\n",i);
}

int main(){
  foo(1, 2);
  return 0;
}
```

I will get a compiler error :

```
test.c:9:5: error: too many arguments to function ‘foo’
```

But if I compile this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
  printf("Hello\n");
}

int main(){
  foo(1, 2);
  return 0;
}
```

I get no errors or warnings.

Could someone explain me why ?

I tested this with gcc 4.6.3 and arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.8.3

EDIT : I compile with all warnings : `gcc -Wall test.c`

Comment: add `-pedantic` to get more warnings

Comment: @mch Thanks for the tip, in that case it does not warn either

Comment: You need -Wstrict-prototypes for gcc to warn about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C, writing `void foo()` means that foo takes an unspecified number of arguments.

To indicate that the function `foo()` should take no arguments, you should write `void foo(void)`

For this reason you should also use the signature `int main(void)`.

Note that K&R function declarations are being removed in the C23 standard, however ( https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2841.htm ).

Comment: nice ! I didn't know that specifying `void` for arguments was different than leaving it empty

Comment: @Quentin It is only so in C. In C++, they are synonymous.

Comment: @PascalCuoq `(void)` is however deprecated in C++, as it is only a backwards-compatible remnant of said C rule. Also, `main(void)`, really ?

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that `gcc` should complain here. Étienne's answer would be right if `f` was an `extern` prototype, but the actual paragraph that discuss this point (6.7.6.3§14 in C11, 6.7.5.3§14 in C99) reads that way (emphasis mine):

> An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. **An empty
>   list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
>   function has no parameters**. The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a
>   definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the
>   parameters is supplied.

`clang` (v3.4) indeed emits a warning (`too many arguments in call to 'foo'`) with your file, but would happily (and silently) compile the following two files:

foo.c:

```
extern void foo();
int main(){
  foo(1, 2);
  return 0;
}
```

bar.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo (int x, int y, int z) { printf("Hello %d\n", z); }
```

results in:

```
$ clang -o foo bar.c foo.c
$ ./foo
Hello 1405669720
```

Comment: +1. Do you know why gcc behaves this way? I searched gcc's documentation but didn't find any reference to this.

Comment: I don't disagree that it *should* warn, but I don't believe it's required to. A function definition with empty parentheses does not provide a prototype. It specifies no parameters (local objects visible inside the function definition), but (in a weird sense) it doesn't specify that the function expects no *arguments*. The syntax is a relic of pre-ANSI C; back then, compilers generally wouldn't warn about parameter mismatches. The lesson: Always use prototypes.

Comment: with gcc, you can define function attribute `__attribute__ format(type, string, check)` that forces the compiler to check `printf()` or `scanf()` function parameters against a format string.

This is probably what you'll find in your standard library headers.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on your warnings!

```
void foo()
```

is an old ANSI C way of declaring a function without a proper prototype. If you do this, the function acts sort of like `void foo(...)`, and allows any number of arguments to be passed.

(In C++, `void foo()` declares a null-arity function as you'd expect).

Comment: I have no warning with ˇgcc -Wall test.c`

Comment: I suppose warnings are compiler-dependent. I do get a warning with Clang.